# shakes at idle in drive but fine at park or neutral

Tags: engine, ignition, sparkplugs, timing-belt

I was driving my 2006 Hyundai sonata (3.3L) yesterday during heavy rain. Suddenly check engine light started flashing. When I stopped at a red light, it started shaking badly. I noticed that when I hit the break in drive mode, rpm drops from 1000 to around 900. But in neutral or in parking mode, it goes back to 1000. My primary guess is either spark plug(s) or coil pack(s) or both gone bad due to some kind of water leakage. I don't think it's timing chain because I don't drive often (it has 105k miles).

Any suggestions?

**UPDATE**
I visited a nearby mechanic and he told me that I got P0018 along with P0300,P0302 and P0304. He needs time to check if the P0018 caused by a stretched timing chain or a bad sensor. I hope it is crankshaft position sensor or Camshaft position sensor. Becuase Timing chain can be expensive (around 1000 dollars I guess).

**UPDATE**
There was a problem with the BANK 2 VARIABLE SOLENOID (part number: TS1109). Replacing that solved the problem.

Comment: try spraying the coils with some water and check for arcing. have you checked the computer for codes? 1000 rpm is pretty high for idle speed. have you checked for vacuum leaks? is the engine dry now? does it still misfire or run poorly?

Comment: I got multiple/random misfires code (P0300). Nope, I did not check for vacum leaks which I will do today. It runs poorly once it heats up but when I start the engine and it is cool,  it runs good for 4/5 minutes. Engine is pretty dry.

Comment: Poke around under the hood for any small rubber hoses (~1/2 to 1" Ø) that are cracked or aren't connected to anything on one end.

Comment: Have you also tried cleaning the MAF? You describe a situation where the engine may be moving from open to closed loop, which would indicate a sensor having issues.